# Span models in Django without a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I'm using Python 2.7/Django 1.8, and am kind of noob.  I'm stuck on creating a filter, with these two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
     name = models.TextField()
     item_id = models.IntegerField()

class B(models.Model):
     entry_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     active = models.BooleanField()
     id = models.IntegerField()
     value = models.IntegerField()
```

The takeaway here is that `A` references `B` by `id`, but there might be multiple entries which have the same id, and all but one have `active = False`.

What I want to do is, essentially:

```
 SELECT a.Name, b.value 
 FROM A a 
 JOIN B b ON a.id = b.item_id and a.active = true
 WHERE a.id = {some value}
```

The only way I can figure it out looks like this:

```
 a_models = A.objects.filter(id=some_value)
 a_ids = [model.item_id for model in a_models]
 return B.objects.filter(active=True, id__in=a_ids)
```

This has the drawback of hitting the database twice, as well as being pretty inefficient.  Is there a way to do this?  Should the models just be designed differently?

---

At the suggestion of rofls, these are the real model names, and the intended usage:

```
class Authorization(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField()
    user_root = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.TextField(max_length=64)

class Value(models.Model):
    entry_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    id = models.IntegerField()
    parent = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.TextField(max_length=64)
    value = models.TextField(max_length=2048)
```

The intent is to for the Values table to store values in a hierarchical manner.  The hierarchy is maintained using parent -> id.  So, for example:

```
 name                value
 /                   ''
 +-> folder1         ''
   +-> value         'some value'
```

would look like this in the Values table:

```
 entry_id | active | id | parent | name    | value
        0 |   True |  1 |      1 |       / | 
        1 |   True |  2 |      1 | folder1 | 
        2 |   True |  3 |      2 |  value1 | some value
```

Note here that id is different from entry_id, and that it allows for history.  For example, changing the value of `id=3`, is a matter of making active False for `entry_id=2`, and entering a new value with `active=True, id=3, parent=2`.  DB-design wise, it's pretty rudimentary stuff.

Where it gets Django complicated (especially for someone like me who is just getting started trying to wrap his head around the ORM), is that since User roles are a kind of value, I figured they belonged in the bit of the application that stores values.  So, `Authorization.user_root` points to an id which is parent to all of the relevant settings.

Sorry for the wall of text.  Here's the actual problem I'm trying to solve: Given a user authorization name, how do I know which users have it?  If this were SQL, the query would look like this:

```
 SELECT a.name, v.value
 FROM Authorization a 
 JOIN Value v ON a.user_root = v.parent and v.active = 1
 WHERE v.name = `{some name}` and v.active = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, not sure if this is the Django way of doing this, but here's what I ended up doing:

```
def get_values(self, env):
    class ValUsers(models.Model):
        name = models.TextField(max_length=64)
        value = models.TextField(max_length=2048)
    ret = EnvUsers.objects.raw(
        'SELECT a.id, a.name, v.value '
        ' FROM Authorization a, Value v ' 
        ' WHERE a.user_root = v.parent '
        '      and a.active = %s '
        '      and v.active = %s '
        '      and v.name = %s ',
        [True, True, env]
    )

    return {u.name: u.value for u in ret}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your models are not linked by a FK, but you can skip one step with this:

```
A.objects.vales_list('item_id', flat=True).filter(id=some_value)
return B.objects.filter(active=True, id__in=a_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should the models just be designed differently?

Yes. You should have a foregin key in your A table to your B table, like so:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(B,through='id')
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
A.objects.filter(b__active=True)
```

See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) for more info.

For instance, many-to-many relationships should work similarly:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    item_id = models.ManyToManyField(B,to_field='id')
```

Also, it's not clear exactly which `id` from `B` you want to use as a `ForeignKey`, so you may actually want this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(B,through='entry_id')
```

Comment: How does this work?  The primary key of B is `entry_id`, but I need to specifically talk about `id`, which may have multiple entries.  Do I just need to define it as `item_id = models.ForeignKey(B, db_column='id')`?

Comment: This talks about many to one relationships in Django models, just for your reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/. 

You were close in your guess, but you should use `item_id = models.ForeignKey(B,to_field='id')`. If the `to_field` is blank, it assumes the Primary Key is what you want to link on.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: First off, thanks for your help/bearing with me.  Second, that doesn't work, since the `id` field is not unique.  So, attempting to create the migration fails with a `'B.id' must set unique=True because it is referenced by a foreign key`.  But, they whole problem is that there might be many entries with `id`.

Comment: Hmm ok, sorry it's not working. I would suggest using the actual model names (such as `Reporter` and `Article`, unless you're working for the NSA). It can make things a lot easier to understand :)

Check out many-to-many relationships:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

I also edited my answer to show how you would do it that way.

Comment: @f00f, actually I think that's because you really want `item_id = models.ForeignKey(B,through='entry_id')`


Your SQL query example doesn't really jive with your models, so it's a little confusing. For instance, you have `a.active=True` in your SQL query but `active` is a field on `B` in your models...

Comment: I'll edit my answer to say what I think you actually need... namely, the `ForeignKey` from `A` to `B` to be `entry_id`, not `id`.

Comment: Namely, your sql says `a.id = b.item_id`, but `B` only has `entry_id`, not `item_id`, in your model.

Comment: I updated the initial question, which I might've done to begin with, but I figured it was easier to talk about A/B.  I looked at the ManyToMany relationship yesterday, and I think it's promising.  This isn't an operation that's used often, so if it turns out that Django ORM doesn't support such a thing, I'll just do it in code.  I figured it was much more likely that Django does support it, I just don't know how to do it.